# How to push reference libraries to github through eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I have included reference libraries in my Eclipse. How do I make eclipse upload them to my github?

Comment: Don't upload that. Use dependency manager to organize dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, with a java project, you don't upload the libraries (jars, which are binaries) in a Git repo (GitHub or any other hosting service)

You declare those dependencies in a `pom.xml` and use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) (or the [Eclipse m2 plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)) to fetch those declared dependencies in your project.
That pom.xml can be added, committed and pushed (it is a simple text file).